# width 100% cut the element when scrolling appears

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page with a horizontal bar that should be as long as the document page. The problem is that when I resize the browser window above the min-height of the body, part of the bar is not showing when I scroll the document.

Searching other similar questions, I've seen that the problem can be resolved by setting the margin and padding of the body style to 0px.

In my case it works if I remove **position:absolute** from the css for the bar. How can I fix this and keep the bar absolutely positioned?

I need to use absolute positioning because I have a div element for the background image that occupies 100% of the page (both vertically and horizontally). The div element does not stay in position if I place the bar after it.

```
<style type"text/css">

html, body
{  
    width: 100%;
    min-width:500px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:700px;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;  
}

#red {
    position:absolute;
     top:100px;
     width:100%;
     min-width:100%;
     height:37%;
     min-height:300px;
     max-height:330px;
     background: rgb(0,0,0);
     margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#background
{
    position:fixed;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     background: rgb(56,54,0);
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
}

</style>

<body>

<div id="background"></div>
<div id="red"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The min-width rule on #red is unnecessary unless you want to declare an absolute length.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `position:relative` in your css.

There is difference between `absolute` and `relative`

**absolute:** `The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.`

**relative:** `The element is positioned relative to its normal position, so "left:20" adds 20 pixels to the element's LEFT position.`

More about `position` on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp or http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: is it necessary use relative? I'm most ease using absolute for all item for not consider nested elements

Answer (score 0):

If you want a background image to cover 100% of the body then add

```
background-image: url(../yourImageHere.jpg)
```

to the css for the body of the page and remove the `#background` div.

You don't need to set html and body width and height to 100% because they default to this anyway. Depending on what you need I've tidied up the css as follows:

```
html, body    {  
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(../yourImageHere.jgp)  
}

#red {
     position:absolute;
     top:100px;
     left:0;
     width:100%;
     min-height:300px;
     max-height:330px;
     background: rgb(0,0,0);
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
}
```